# Sum 2 Columns in Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to sum two columns that i have in LINQ. The following is my LINQ statement

```
var SigmaGood =  from n in db.tbl_dppITHr
                 where n.ProductionHour >= SelectedDateDayShiftStart
                 where n.ProductionHour <= SelectedDateEnd
                 select n.part1 + n.part2

ViewData["GoodTotal"] = SigmaGood.Sum();
```

I am trying to get a total for part1 + part2;

When i try and test the result i dont get any value back i get a blank.

Anyone any ideas what i am doing incorrect?

[image]

Comment: The result of `Sum` is always a number, even when you sum *no* elements, so getting "a blank" is impossible. Please specify what you actually get.

Comment: What is a _blank_? If the columns are numeric columns you cannot get a white-space.

Comment: That's why I think they are reading a different key from `ViewData`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth `Queryable.Sum` might very well return `null`. @Yosi had the correct answer but deleted it.

Comment: @Magnus: And in what circumstances? Please provide us with input values that make `Sum` return `null`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth In Linq2Sql if all the values are `null` the result of `Sum` is null. Did a simple test in Linqpad (using a test DB): `tblSystems.Where (s => s.fkSystemID == null).Select (s => s.fkSystemID).Sum()` and the result is `null`

Comment: @Magnus: Ah, the joys of implementation details. I have to admit, I completely neglected the fact that the OP probably doesn't use `Enumerable.Sum` but `Queryable.Sum`. Thanks for pointing it out. This is kind of embarrassing actually... :-)

Comment: @Yosi undelete your answer, it appears to be useful and or correct after all!

Answer (score 1):

I would say blank must mean the key you're storing the value against doesn't match the key you are reading/displaying. If it did you would at least see `0`, not blank.

Do it in two steps and debug it.

```
var total = sigmaGood.Sum();
ViewData["GoodTotal"] = total; //breakpoint on this line and check value of total.
```

Or hardcode a test value, I bet it still comes out blank:

```
ViewData["GoodTotal"] = 1234;
```

Comment: When i do that Total Equals Null

Comment: @Inkey: As I already said in my comment to the question, that's impossible. Please show a screenshot.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I think that guy with the `null` check was onto something! I guess if they are all `null`. `Sum` returns `null`. Checking it out now.

Comment: @weston: Nope: `new int?[] { null, null }.Sum()` returns `0` and not `null`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth hmm, then I wonder why the signature of `Sum<IEnumerable<Nullable<Int32>>` returns a `Nullable<Int32>` if `null` is never returned?

Comment: @weston: I honestly have no idea, but the documentation and the tests are clear on what is happening. `new int?[0].Sum();` is returning `0` just as well.

Comment: @Inkey: You need to check the value of `total` *after* that line has executed. In other words, put the break point on the line *after* the one it is on now and then check again.

Comment: That is the value after the line has executed

Comment: @weston: Because the actual signature is `T Sum<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` and thus there is no way to unwrap the nullable in the signature.

Comment: @Inkey what type is `total`? hover over the `var` to tell. Also you haven't written any of your own extension methods that might also be called `Sum` have you?

Comment: Total DataType = int32?

Comment: There is no such thing as Sum<T>(IEnumerable<T>). Furthermore, this is probably querying an IQueryable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `part1` and `part2` has value?

```
var SigmaGood =  from n in db.tbl_dppITHr
                 where n.ProductionHour >= SelectedDateDayShiftStart
                 where n.ProductionHour <= SelectedDateEnd
                 select n.part1 ?? 0 + n.part2 ?? 0

ViewData["GoodTotal"] = SigmaGood.Sum();
```

Comment: That doesn't change the outcome. Even when they where nullables without a value, the result of `Sum` would be `0` and not "a blank".

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - and if one is `null` and the other is `7`?

Comment: `7` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156065.aspx "The result does not include values that are null."

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sum = db.tbl_dppITHr.Where(n => n.ProductionHour >= SelectedDateDayShiftStart
                                    && n.ProductionHour <= SelectedDateEnd)
                        .Sum(n => n.part1 + n.part2);
```

Comment: That doesn't compile and when you fix the compilation error it is no different from the code of the OP

Comment: Now it does compile. Does the same as the question though

Comment: I know, I'm not the answerer so I just fixed some little mistake not changing the answer

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz: Are you talking to yourself? ;-)

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth. No I was answering your comment

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz: My comment didn't contain a question. And your second comment doesn't look like it talks to me...

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain you don't have a `null` in your input data? That may be rendered as a SQL `SUM()` which would go to `null` if any input value is `null`.

Comment: Yes 100% if it is null my values in the database will be 0

Comment: @Inkey: `DECLARE @i int = NULL; SELECT SUM(@i)` returns `NULL` in SQL Server 2008 R2.